# Linux does not use the same cc program found in $PATH

Tags: linux, gcc

I installed another version of gcc (9.2.0) to a non-default folder in my Linux machine and pointed $PATH to that new location. `gcc` and `g++` are working but there is no `cc` so I made a symlink:

```
ln -s $HOME/.local/bin/gcc $HOME/.local/bin/cc
```

I thought `cc` now points to the correct one

```
$ ~/.local/bin/cc --version
cc (GCC) 9.2.0

$ which cc
~/.local/bin/cc
```

but without the full path, `cc` still uses the old version

```
$ cc --version
cc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-16)
```

I could not understand how this could happen. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `and pointed $PATH to that new location` - have you *prepended* the location to the previous value of $PATH?

Comment: Well, that's pretty obvious. Your distribution (whatever it is, looks like Red Hat), comes with GCC 4.8.5. Then you (or someone else) installed GCC 9.2.0 in `/usr/local` (either intentionally, or by forgetting the `--prefixe=/usr` option during build of GCC). So you have two versions of the compiler installed. In your `.bashrc` you can set an alias of `alias cc='/path/to/gcc/you/want'` and then `cc` will be correct for your environment. You can also just `export cc=~/.local/bin/cc` from the command line. `~/.local/bin/cc` itself is also a soft-link.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk the output of `which cc` command is the new location so I think the $PATH is correct. To be more specific, I have `export PATH=~/.local/bin:$PATH` in `~/.bashrc`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin yes that's what I did. I installed intentionally to $HOME/.local but the question is why `cc --version` is 4.8.5 while `which cc` is `~/.local/bin/cc` and `~/.local/bin/cc --version` is 9.2.0

Comment: Because your default path includes `$HOME`, not `$HOME/.local`. You have to adjust that. Check `echo $PATH` to confirm what you have.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I'm afraid I don't get what you mean. The `$PATH` env is currently  `/home/xxx/bin:/home/xxx/.local/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/opt/ibutils/bin:/opt/openlava-2.2/bin:/home/xxx/.local/bin:/home/xxx/bin`

Comment: `/home/xxx/.local/bin` is there. The issue is now "Where is the soft-link to the current `cc` defined?" If there is an existing `alias` or `soft-link` of `cc` to `gcc` (4.8.5), you have to turn that off. Use `type cc` and `type -p cc` to check for aliases and link locations. On my system, the main softlink  is `/usr/bin/cc -> /usr/bin/gcc`. I suspect you will have the same. Since `/usr/bin` will be in your path too, you need to remove that softlink (temporarily) or use another link like `lcc` for local cc. If you use makefiles, just set the new path in the makefile.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin thanks it's working now. I re-login so I could not check the previous results of  the `type` command.

Comment: Glad you got it working, good luck with your coding!